# How to access Delta Comfort+ price and seatmap with Amadeus APIs?

Tags: amadeus

I need help retrieving flight offers and seat map information for Delta Comfort+ seats using the Amadeus flight APIs.

I've seen Comfort+ described as "both fare and ancillary seat purchase options" that are "booked in W and S classes", and [this site](https://pro.delta.com/content/agency/gb/en/products-and-services/in-flight/delta-comfort-plus.html#) gives methods for recognizing a Comfort+ offer using the fare basis code.

I think I've tried most or all of the parameters in the Flight Offers Search API (shopping/flight-offers) and haven't been able to get back any results I can identify as Comfort+ using those methods.

I've also tried the upsell API (/shopping/flight-offers/upselling), which I can get to return main cabin offers based on a submitted basic economy offer, but nothing higher.

And in the seatmap API (/shopping/seatmaps), I'm only seeing seats in the economy section and not those in the Comfort+ section... probably because I've only been able to submit economy flight offers to it.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

**---- added in response to jabrena's request --------------------------**

After a bunch of trial and error, I was able to locate a Comfort+ offer and retrieve a seatmap of the Comfort+ section of the main cabin. The steps were:

- search flight-offers using pricingOptions.noPenaltyFare=true or pricingOptions.refundableFare=true. (Without these pricingOptions, the returned offers couldn't be upgraded to comfort+ using the upselling API)
- submit one of the returned flight offers to the upselling API
- locate a returned offer with a fareDetailsBySegment.class of S or W and submit it to the seatmap API.

Here is the flight-offers call (using the Node SDK). The upselling and seatmap calls were populated as I described above

```
amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.post(JSON.stringify({
    currencyCode: "USD",
    originDestinations: [
        {
            id: "1",
            originLocationCode: 'MSP',
            destinationLocationCode: 'ARN',
            departureDateTimeRange: {
                date: '2022-04-14'
            }
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            originLocationCode: 'ARN',
            destinationLocationCode: 'MSP',
            departureDateTimeRange: {
                date: '2022-04-18'
            }
        }
    ],
    travelers: [
        {
            id: "1",
            travelerType: "ADULT"
        }
    ],
    sources: [
        "GDS"
    ],
    searchCriteria: {
        maxFlightOffers: 200,
        additionalInformation: {
            brandedFares: true
        },
        allowAlternativeFareOptions : true,
        flightFilters: {
            carrierRestrictions: {
                includedCarrierCodes: [
                    "DL",
                    "AF",
                    "KL"
                ]
            }
        },
        pricingOptions: {
            noPenaltyFare: true
        }
    }
    })).then(function (response) {
        resolve(response); 
    }).catch(function (response) {
        resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

Couple points:

- I tried the offers API's pricingOptions in a bunch of different combinations. Using pricingOptions.noPenaltyFare=true or pricingOptions.refundableFare=true were the only ways I could get back offers with the classes that would cause the upselling API to return Comfort+ offers
- using the PREMIUM_ECONOMY cabinRestriction returned offers that are a class above Comfort+, with seats located outside of the Comfort+ section
- using pricingOptions = 'noRestrictionFare=true' returns class Y (full fare), but submitting that to seatmap returns only the non-comfort+ seats, and submitting a Y class offer to the upsell API returned only 1st class (Delta One) and economy amenities... not a Comfort+ option

---

This feels a little random, and I'm not confident that this is the best way to approach this... Is there any documentation that can help reduce the guesswork?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Can you provide the HTTP Calls that you are sending with no success?

Comment: So currently, you find a way to get the data, but you would like to know if exist other ways with less API calls, right?

Comment: Thanks @jabrena ... yes, I haven't been able to find Amadeus documentation that describes how to populate the APIs to accomplish goals like this, or how to interpret responses. The self-service API pages do a good job of outlining the fields in each individual API, but don't go any deeper.

A pointer to more thorough descriptions of how the airlines use the input values and how to interpret the results would be very helpful. Maybe that would be documentation for the Amadeus system itself, and not the API?

Comment: Hi @fmckinney, sorry the delay but exist another way combining: /shopping/availability/flight-availabilities to get all classes for an itinerary, /shopping/flight-offers + /shopping/flight-offers/pricing

Comment: Tell me if it fits for you. Have a good day